# file_get_contents в C

Tags: c

Переучиваюсь с PHP на C.
Есть файл text.txt 
Мне нужно получить из
файла саму строку. Как это сделать?

```
FILE * handler = fopen("test", "r");
if(handler == NULL){
    printf("Cannot open file \n");
    exit(1);
}
```

Не знаю что делать дальше

Comment: `malloc`+`fread`, вестимо.

Comment: fscanf для чтения форматированного текста

Comment: Зачем нужен malloc? Это же аллокатор памяти вроде? Типо в буфер сувать нужно?

Comment: Так что, собственно, нужно? Читать файл построчно? Тогда [fgets](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) или GNU [getline](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getline)

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы в переменной типа string оказалось содержимое файла. Такое возможно?

Comment: В Си нет типа `string` (кстати, если хотите, чтобы человек, к которому вы обращаетесь в комментарии увидел оповещение, то используйте @NICK). По поводу вопроса -- да, это не слишком сложная функция. Определяете размер открытого файла (fseek/ftell), выделяете буфер нужного размера (malloc),  перматываете файл к началу (rewind) и читаете файл (fread) в этот буфер.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда-то давно написал пару функций для этого. Пара советов по использованию:

1. Подразумевается, что в обе функции передается валидный указатель на уже открытый ([`fopen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen)) файл.
2. Закрывать ([`fclose`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fclose)) файл нужно в вызывающем коде, ровно как и освобождать ([`free`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free)) созданную строку с содержимым файла.

---

```
long get_file_size(FILE* file) {
    /* Перемещаемся в конец файла. */
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);

    /* Получаем текущую позицию в файле (размер). */
    const long fsize = ftell(file);
    if (fsize == -1)
        perror("Can't get the current value of the file position.\n");

    /* Перемещаемся в начало файла. */
    rewind(file);
    return fsize;
}
```

```
char* get_text_from_file(FILE* file) {
    /* Получаем размер файла и проверяем, успешно ли получение. */
    const long fsize = get_file_size(file);
    if (fsize == -1)
        return NULL;

    /* Выделяем память для строки, в которую скопируется содержимое файла. */
    char* const src = malloc(fsize+1);
    if (src == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't allocate %ld bytes for the text of the file.\n", fsize+1);
        return NULL;
    }

    /* Записываем содержимое файла в строку. Добавляем нуль-терминатор. */
    const size_t read_size = fread(src, 1, fsize, file);
    src[read_size] = '\0';

    return src;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо... Помогло

Comment: Наверное неплохо было бы еще и размер файла из `get_text_from_file()` сразу получать (например, через еще один аргумент)

Comment: @avp, а для чего он может пригодиться? Тем более, можно отдельно функцию `get_file_size` вызвать.

Comment: @eanmos, для удобства программирования -) А отдельно все можно вызвать, например `fstat(fileno(file), &st_buf);`

Comment: @avp, возможно вы и правы :) Кстати, спасибо за `fstat` — не знал про такую