# Скопировать символ в char на C

Tags: c, native

Работаю с `android jni`. В цикле получаю код символа.Имеем

```
char* buf = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char));
```

нужно в `buf` скопировать символ с кодом например `100`.Пробовал через `memcpy` и `memmove` но не могу понять как.

```
int code = 100;
memcpy(buf, &code, 1);
```

вылетает приложение непонятно почему.Как скопировать символ по его коду в `buf`?

Comment: для примера написал 100

Comment: Где-то в другом месте вылетает. С тем `memcpy`, что вы написали в вопросе все нормально

Comment: я его просто уже исправил из ответа ниже

Comment: Зачем тут вообще `memcpy`? Откуда взялась идея копировать один символ через `memcpy`?

Comment: с интернета взялаь.А как мне еще строку собрать?

Comment: Обычный опрепатор присваивания запишет вам один символ туда, куда скажете.

Comment: нужно к строке неизвестной длины(изначально 0) прибавить посимвольно.

Comment: Зачем такие сложности, при такой размерности делается так `buf[0] = (unsigned)code;`, что б не было "расширения по знаку"  я добавил unsigned. Поведение будет аналогично правильно-записаному memcpy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Синопсис**
>
> ```
> #include <string.h>
> void *memcpy(void * restrict s1, void * restrict s2, size_t n);
> ```
>
> **Описание**
>
> Функция `memcpy` копирует `n` символов из объекта, на который указывает `s2`, в объект, на который указывает `s1`. Если копирование происходит
>   между перекрывающимися объектами, поведение не определено.

Второй аргумент `memcpy` — это **адрес** источника, а не сам источник. А у вас получается так, что `memcpy` пытается получить значение из адреса 100, что приводит к падению приложения.

Попробуйте так:

```
char* buf = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char));
int code = 100;

const char ch = (char) code;
memcpy(buf, &ch, 1);
```

Кстати, вам обязательно нужно использовать `memcpy`? Почему бы не сделать так:

```
*buf = (char) code;
```

**Примечания**

1. `sizeof(char)` по стандарту равен 1:

   > When `sizeof` is applied to an operand that has type `char`, `unsigned char`, or `signed char`, (or a qualified version thereof) the result is 1.

   Так что можно писать `char *buf = (char *) malloc(1);`.
2. Приводить возвращаемое значение `malloc` к определенному типу *не нужно*. См. этот [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/761113/char-malloc).
   Так что лучше будет писать `char *buf = malloc(sizeof *buf);`.

Comment: Про функцию знаю.Делал так.В общем я побайтно читаю файл.Имею int code.Так вот нужно code скопировать.

Comment: Ну приведите `int` к `char` (если у вас однобайтная кодировка).

Comment: По всякому делал.(char) code

Comment: Я же говорю, что делать вот так: `memcpy(buf, (char) 100, 1)` нельзя. Т. к. второй аргумент `memcpy` должен быть **адресом** источника, а не самим источником. А у вас получается так, что `memcpy` получает значение из адреса 100, что приводит к падению приложения.

Comment: вопрос дополнил как я делаю

Comment: @Ivan, скомпилировал в ideone ([ссылка](https://ideone.com/FUGryj)).

Comment: Спасибо.char ch = (char) code придется использовать в цикле.Не будет перерасход памяти?

Comment: @Ivan, Был рад помочь :) Перерасхода, конечно не будет. Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его галочкой (слева от ответа).

Comment: Для моих целей лучше memmove или memcpy?

Comment: @Ivan, Для ваших целей лучше `*buf = (char) code`. А вообще, разница между [`memmove`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memmove) и [`memcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy) в том, что первая позволяет копировать перекрывающиеся области памяти, следовательно `memmove` зачастую медленнее, чем `memcpy`.

Comment: *buf = (char) code не пойдет.Мне нужно считать все байты в одну строку

Comment: @Ivan, что `memcpy`, что `memmove`, что `*buf = code` в конечном счете просто поместят символ в `buf`. Так что все три способа делают одно и то же. Следовательно, вам *должны* подойти все три способа.

Comment: Что бы к buf прибавить еще символы нужно memcpy(buf + strlen(buf), &ch, 1); верно?

Comment: @Ivan, если вам нужно считать содержимое файла в строку, то посмотрите [этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/833081/file-get-contents-%d0%b2-c/834665#834665) (обратите внимание на комментарий @avp к ответу). Нет, ваш пример будет работать не верно: 1) Вы выделяете один байт для `buf`, следовательно большее кол-во байт просто не влезет; 2) `strlen` работает только для [нуль-терминируемых](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0) строк.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78687/discussion-between-eanmos-and-ivan).

Comment: заждался в комнате

Comment: Зачем так сложно то, проще: `char but = (char)code;`

Comment: @NewView, это долгая история :) См. чат

Answer (score 1):

```
int code = 100;
memcpy(&buf, &code, sizeof(char));
```

А вообще так еще проще

```
char a = (char)100;
```

Answer (score -2):

Вот что я хотел

```
char* buf = malloc(1);
int code = 100;
int l = 0;

memset(buf ,0,1);

for(int i = 0;i<10;i++){
    const char ch = (char) code + i;
    memcpy(buf + l, &ch, strlen(&ch));
    l++;
}
printf("%s\r\n", buf);
free(buf);
```

Comment: А вы не забыли о NULL символе в си строке?

Comment: Помню но он вроде тут и не нужен

Comment: Это бессмыслица какая-то. Размер буфера - 1. Вы пишете туда 10 символов с вылетом за пределы выделенной памяти. Символа 0 в конце строки - нет. При чем и зачем здесь вообще `memcpy` с самого начала - не ясно.

Comment: Полностью согласен с @AnT. Да и копирование памяти тут совсем не нужно, можно разыменовать указатель с `offset` и записать туда символ...

Comment: На java будет так String s = "a";s = s + "b";.s стала ab.Нужно такое же на c для этого и нужно memcpy

Comment: @LLENN покажите как

Comment: @Ivan, вам нужно использовать [`strcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy). Только сначала прочитайте о C-строках ([здесь](http://youngcoder.ru/lessons/9/simvolnie_stroki_vvod_i_vyvod.php), например).

Comment: ок.На счет кодировки не подскажите?https://ideone.com/L4hu2q

Comment: @Ivan, боже мой... Извините, если звучит грубо, конечно, но... вам же тысячу раз сказали, что в буфере не хватает места. Вы выделяете память под один элемент (`malloc(--> 1 <--)`), а записывает аж 10!

Comment: @Ivan, что именно с кодировкой?

Comment: Я переделывать буду.Вопрос если будет места хватать то русские символы будут нормально отображаться?

Comment: Кракозябры.Нужно руский символ что бы был русским английский английским и т.д.

Comment: @Ivan, про кодировки смотрите [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/459154/%d0%a0%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8/459299#459299).

Comment: я не с консолью работаю

Comment: @Ivan, [How to use UTF-8 in C code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30388085/how-to-use-utf-8-in-c-code)

Comment: До кодировок кажеться ещё рановато :) зачем в принципе выделять память? Статический буфер размером 11 вам поможет :) вместо memcpy: `buf[I] = ch; ` в цикле `for`, после цикла: `buf[10] = '\0'` вместо memset: `char buf[11] = {0};`

Comment: и `l` у вас по сути ровна `i`, лишняя она :)

Comment: Цикл for для примера дабы один и тот жк символ не выводить для этого и i

Comment: Для примера взял 10.а так качаю с интернета файл неизвестной длины